# excel vba insert formula for empty cell with vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

i don't know how to add this formula in vba and make it dynamic with a range

```
the formula is: =ALS(L9="";"";M9*VERT.ZOEKEN(L9;'Database Freon'!B2:C20;2;0))

Database OU Column L = text
Database OU column M = number
Database OU Column N = number
Database Freon B Column = text
Database Freon C column = number
formula is at Column N or if better other column but value to Column N
```

the formula calculates M * C = N

now i want this formula run every time the workbook is opened to fill all the empty cells on Database OU Column N

thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Look up `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`, 2) `Workbook_Open()` event.  Look up those two items and you should be on your way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

```
Range("N6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]="""","""",RC[-1]*VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'Database Freon'!B2:C20,2,0))"

Range("N6").Select

Selection.Copy
Do While True
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value) And IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value) Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
    End If
Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: ill give it a try

Comment: it just paste formula in the cell but as text not als a working formula

Comment: and its not placing it in the empty cells but in the hole range N

Comment: one small issue when the cell setting is text it paste this formula =IF(RC[-2]="","",RC[-1]*VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'Database Freon'!B2:C6,2,0)) but if the cell setting is on default it paste this code =ALS(L2="";"";M2*VERT.ZOEKEN(L2;'Database Freon'!'B2':$F:$F;2;0)) that gives a formula error #Name